# Accessing remote SQL server from ASP classic not working on a specific computer

Tags: sql-server, iis, asp-classic, database-connection

I have 2 computers that try to access a remote SQL server through a piece of code written in Classic ASP

Both of the computers are in the same LAN (therefor - same external IP address)

On computer A (which has Windows 7 installed) - the connection works fine, while on Computer B (with Windows 8) - I get the following error:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'

[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.
```

Both trying to run the script from a local IIS in the default website with the default Application Pool

I've tried enabling 32bit application to run on 64bit OS - didn't work

The code I'm trying to run is as simple as:

```
<%@ language="vbscript" codepage="65001" %>
<%  
session.CodePage = 65001

dim ServerName , sqlUser, sqlPasw, sqlDBName, Conn

ServerName  = "SERVER IP"
sqlUser     = "USER"
sqlPasw     = "PASSWPRD"
sqlDBName   = "DBNAME"


Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

Conn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Cstr(ServerName) & " ;Uid=" & Cstr(sqlUser) & ";Pwd=" & Cstr(sqlPasw) & ";Database=" & Cstr(sqlDBName)
Conn.Close

Set Conn = Nothing  

%>
```

Comment: Have you tried an OLEDB conection string rather than ODBC.  See here for examples - http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the problem and it was ridiculous

The problem was the extra space here (before the `Uid` part of the connection string):

```
Conn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Cstr(ServerName) & " ;Uid=" & Cstr(sqlUser) & ";Pwd=" & Cstr(sqlPasw) & ";Database=" & Cstr(sqlDBName)
```

I have no idea why is this working on Windows 7 and not on Windows 8 - but that what happened

(According to [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms722656%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - trailing and opening whitespaces should be ignored - so the right behavior is the one that works)

If someone knows why is that - it would be nice to know

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check firewall configuration on Windows 8. I had to disable it(firewall) on Win8 because no configuration changes help SQL to get through.

Comment: Did you try creating an exception for sqlserv.exe, both in- and outbound? disabling the firewall altogether seems like a bit too drastic measure.

Comment: I did and that was the only solution which worked.Considering the fact that it worked on Win7 and all of a sudden stop working on Win8 I think there is a problem with firewall in win8 of which Microsoft cutely aware off.. In any case for computers on business network it should not be an issue, we are after all protected by multy layered security

Comment: I forgot to mention that I had telnet connection on that port...
Any way - I found the problem, I'll post the answer
Thanks!